# Unexpected end of input jQuery json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make a ajax account submission form, but once the user pressed sign up, and they made a mistake, they can't click sign up again because I get an "Unexpected end of input"

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            console.log(obj);
            if (obj.status == 'success') {
                console.log("successfull login");
            } else {
                $("#register-form .response").html(obj.errors[0]);
                $("#register-form .response").slideDown(500);
            }
        }
    });
```

it says the error happens on `console.log(response);`, but not on the first try, only after that.

Hope you can help

Comment: What does the JSON response look like?  That's (probably) where the problem is.

Comment: Don't do `$.parseJSON(response)` in your callback.  Add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax` to tell jQuery to do that for you.

Comment: Might be a proxy or firewall problem

Comment: ok found the problem, was something with my php, sorry and thanks for the suggestions